# Spring 4 websocket + stomp + rabbitmq and clustering

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

I am going through Spring 4 websocket + stomp + rabbitmq(RabbitMQ-Web-Stomp plugin) architecture and I have a question about clustering. As per my understanding here Spring MVC act as a gateway for STOMP requests. If we cluster the application instance with spring web socket configuration will it create any confusion? For an example will it open multiple listeners and how will in such a case this architecture behave?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you would need to use load balancing and a message broker. I used HAProxy to load balance 4 Spring MVC instances (websocket) running on 4 tomcat servers. Also configure rabbit mq as a broker. From client code connect to the single HAProxy url.

If you don't use the message broker, then the websocket client subscriptions will be maintained in the app/ web server's (tomcat) JVM and in case one instance goes down, all the subscriptions on that would be lost.